# Inversion is a continuous map of a topological field?

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

> If $F$ is a field equipped with an absolute value, then inversion on $F^{\times}$ is a continuous map.

I don't know how to prove this statement, I had tried showing that  $\{y;\,y\in F^{\times},\,  y=1/x, |x-x_0|<r\}$ is still open(an open ball is mapped to an open set), but it seems complicated, help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that the topology is induced by the absolute value. Let $x_0\in F^*$, consider $|x-x_0|<r$ and $|x-x_0|<r\subset F^*$, you have $|x|\geq |x_0|-r$
You have $|{1\over x}-{1\over x_0}| ={{|x-x_0|}\over |xx_0|}\leq {{|x-x_0|}\over {|x_0|(|x_0|-r)}}={r\over{|x_0|(|x_0|-r)}}$. Now, for every $c>0$, choose $r$ such that ${r\over{|x_0|(|x_0|-r)}}<c$.

Comment: Isn't the first inequality $\geq$?

Comment: what inequality   ?

Comment: ${{|x-x_0|}\over |xx_0|}\leq {{|x-x_0|}\over {|x_0|(|x_0|+r)}}$